# Is .bind() the same as a closure when first param in null?

Tags: javascript

I've seen code like this multiple times:

```
function something(a,b,c) {
    return a+b+c // or something else with a,b,c
}.bind(null, 1, 2);
...
something(3);
```

Is this the same as returning a closure?

```
function something(a,b,c) {
    return function(c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }
}

let binded = something(1,2);
binded(3);
```

I'm a bit confused with this kind of code because the documentation says it is used to bind `this` but in these cases the first parameter is `null`. After a while I came to the conclusion that's similar to the closure and now I wonder if that was just an alternate way to write the same thing.

Comment: With `.bind`, `this` would be bound to `null` and could not not be changed anymore, no matter how the function is called. In the closure case `this` could still be set. Of course if the function doesn't use `this` it doesn't matter .

Comment: It appears to be a curry pattern.  `.bind` is being used to partially pre-apply some of the arguments of the function, the result is a function that can be repeatedly used more concisely later on.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it behaves identically because both functions have access to the encapsulated values that aren't editable anymore.

But generally I would say that a closure is much mightier because its not restricted to parameter values only.

Also it's good to know that bound functions are `[native code]` when stringifying them via `toString`-method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can call it an exotic function. I don't know the exact definition, but I believe it is simply binding the arguments to the scope of the function at the time it is ran. We use it for dependency injection to get all the dependencies in to the root scope.

`null` is specified because the arguments are not bound to any specific context, so your example is equivalent to calling `something(3, 1, 2)` as viewed from inside `something()` but you don't need to declare `1, 2` when you run it.

Here is a good video that shows an example of it being used in practice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kpEP4JeEdc (starting about 7 mins in).